# Researching this product: V Blade Mandoline Slicer

Tags: patent-search

Im researching into these V blade slicers and accordingly the first V-blade slicers, mader by Borner, patents expired back in 1989.

Here's a patent they had but expired:

https://www.google.co.uk/patents/US4290196?dq=borner+v+blade+slicer&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CFkQ6AEwCDgKahUKEwjx7t61lNrGAhXCzIAKHXwVC7k

And another:

https://www.google.co.uk/patents/US5075973?dq=borner+v+blade+slicer&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CFIQ6AEwBzgKahUKEwjx7t61lNrGAhXCzIAKHXwVC7k

However they keep applying for new patents for products with similar features.

Example of patent here:

https://www.google.co.uk/patents/US7322112?dq=v+blade+slicer&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAGoVChMI37yNu5XaxgIVC40NCh37ggU_

The product i've researched into is this:

[http://www.amazon.com/Kitchen-Elite-Blade-Mandoline-Slicer/dp/B00KOUH16M/ref=sr_1_7?s=home-garden&ie=UTF8&qid=1436691809&sr=1-7&keywords=mandoline+slicer+professional&pebp=1436691808242&perid=00Z1BWXAZ2P9M684NBZW](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00KOUH16M)

Quite a few sellers sell this item but not sure would it infringe on any patents from Borner.

Hope someone can help because this situation is rather confusing.

Thanks

Ben

Comment: Welcome to Ask Patents! Would it be possible for you to list out a specific patent (namely, a claim or two from the patent) that you're curious about? We can sometimes help with requests like this, if they're phrased right, but we need a bit more information to go off of. Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Hi I've updated the question with the patents involved. Hope someone can help.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Now that we've got that information, could you clarify a bit about what specifically you're wondering about? I understand that there's this product sold on Amazon, and what appears to be another company has some patents on a related invention that they've been improving over the years.

Comment: Are you wondering about whether the product infringes on those patents? If so, I'd appreciate if you could include some details, like that you feel the blade design infringes on the first claim of the second listed patent, or whatever else it may be. It doesn't have to be *quite* that specific, but the more detail, the better. On the other hand, are you curious about the legality of re-filing for expired patents and what that company is doing?

Comment: Specifics go a long way to finding you the best answer possible, the soonest, and making sure that future users can find your question if they're curious about the same thing.

Comment: No worries about the broadness of the question to start with--the [se] network has some pretty strict rules about how questions and answers should be structured, all in the name of getting you, and people in the future, better and more concise answers to the questions you're asking. It can be difficult to get everything right the first time, but willingness to improve the question goes a long way. You can get a bit more information on our best practices by visiting our [help center](/help/how-to-ask), but I'm also happy to help here or on [meta] whenever you have more specific questions.

Comment: HI, I feel the blade design may infringe those patents. ANy advice?